# plotly table how to align header vertical and horizontal

Tags: python, plotly

i already had a look at the documentation, without success. i am looking for a solution to align the header - vertical and horizontal. the horizontal align do not work for the second row (the word "center" is not in the center). the two headers are not at the same level, is there a solution to align the vertical position?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
    header=dict(values=['this is not center', 'B Scores'],
                line_color='darkslategray',
                fill_color='lightskyblue',
                align='center'),
    cells=dict(values=[[100, 100, 100, 300], # 1st column
                       [90, 90, 90, 270]], # 2nd column
               line_color='darkslategray',
               fill_color='lightcyan',
               align='center'))
])
fig.update_layout(width=250, height=130)
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=0, r=0, t=0, b=0))
fig.show()
```

thanks for help

update: if i set the text in bold and i can fix the same level for the headers. to get the word "center" into center i use space character.

```
header=dict(values=['<b>this is not</b><br>   center', '<b>B Scores']
```

[image]

Comment: How are you showing your figure? JupyterLab? Something else?

Comment: i save it as image: plotly.io.write_image(fig, file='table.png', format='png')

Answer (score 0):

## Using instead a Plotly Dash table

AFAIAA, the Plotly `go.Table` built-in style formatting customization functionality is quite limited.

However, an excellent obvious alternative solution would be to use Dash (by Plotly), and more specifically the [Dash DataTable](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable) built-in component (`dash.dash_table.DataTable`). Which in contrast to the Plotly table allows for all the HTML & CSS customization you could imagine; straight from within your Python code.

For example, the following:

```py
import pandas as pd

import dash
from dash import dcc, html, callback, dash_table
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "this is now center": [100, 100, 100, 300],
        "B Scores": [90, 90, 90, 270],
    }
)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dash_table.DataTable(
            id="table",
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
            data=df.to_dict("records"),
            style_table={"height": "250px", "overflowY": "auto"},
            style_header={
                "backgroundColor": "lightskyblue",
                "fontWeight": "bold",
                "textAlign": "center",
                "verticalAlign": "middle",
            },
            style_cell={
                "textAlign": "center",
                "overflow": "hidden",
                "textOverflow": "ellipsis",
                "maxWidth": 0,
            },
            style_cell_conditional=[
                {
                    "if": {"column_id": "this is now center"},
                    "width": "40%",
                    "whiteSpace": "normal",
                    "padding": "3px",
                },
                {
                    "if": {"column_id": "B Scores"},
                    "width": "40%",
                    "whiteSpace": "normal",
                    "padding": "3px",
                },
            ],
        ),
        html.Br(),
        dcc.Input(
            id="input-box",
            type="text",
            value="B Scores",
            style={"width": "500px"},
        ),
    ],
    style={"width": "200px", "margin": "20px"},
)

# Define callback to update table header
@callback(Output("table", "columns"), [Input("input-box", "value")])
def update_table_header(input_value):
    new_columns = [
        {"name": "this is now center", "id": "this is now center"},
        {"name": input_value, "id": "B Scores"},
    ]
    return new_columns


app.run(jupyter_mode="tab") # Remove the jupyter param if not running from notebook
```

yields:
[image: Video screen shot recording of dash app as ran from code above]